# How to convert binary protobuf file to json file in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, maven, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers

In my project I have proto file, the respective class files also. I have probuf binary data as blob file format. How can I convert this file to json file? I am very new to Scala.

I came across https://scalapb.github.io/docs/ site. It is not very clear to me. I do not want to install this whole but rather just make use of Json4s to convert protobuf data to json data.

Any pointers? Which library can I use and how can I use it?

Comment: Does this help? https://scalapb.github.io/docs/json/

Comment: @stefanobaghino : I have been to this page. It's not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. The .proto files are your source of truth. There should be no "respective class files"
2. ScalaPB should be used as an SBT plugin. It will generate "managed" code when you compile your project.  That managed code will consist of case classes that mirror the definitions in the proto files and companion objects that can serialize the protobufs.
3. Managed code is code you do not edit as a user. You won't even see it unless you look for it in the target directory. If your proto files change, the compiler will re-create the proper code to reflect those changes. That is why you should not hand-create these case class files.
4. Then apply their `Json4s` helper-lib which cuts down on a few steps